# Multiple Input fields in a JavaFX TextInputDialog?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, java-8, textfield

I'm trying to ask the user for multiple fields of information (Name, Age, etc). Here is the code I did to try to do that:

```
public void initialize(Stage mainStage) {
    ...
    button.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> handleAddUser(mainStage));
    ...
}

public void handleAddUser(Stage mainStage) {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();

    dialog.initOwner(mainStage);
    dialog.setTitle("Adding A New User");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Add User");
    dialog.setContentText("Name: ");

    Optional<String> name = dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

Right now, this code works in getting the `name`, but I'd like to have additional fields inside this dialog to be able to ask for other things like age, favorite color, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be a text input dialog? You can achieve the same with other methods.

Comment: I can't give any code at the moment, but you can probably get some inspiration from this post. They make a custom login dialog a bit down: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/